# How to get string from odd's array ?

Tags: javascript, string

I need help... I'm learning JavaScript, and it seems easy, but I may just be overlooking... everything... My problem is I need to return a string of all the even numbers between 0 and num inclusive; ex 7 gets you 0246, etc. I've gotten:

```
function stringOfEvens(num) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= num.length; ++i) {
    if (i % 2 === 0 ); {
      return i;
   }
  }
}
```

I know the whole outlook is to run a for loop that goes from 0 to the number in question appending each time and if that number % 2 = 0, return that number, but something is a miss... I may even be overthinking and approaching this whole thing wrong... It is figuratively driving me mad...

Comment: What is `num` (an int or a string? You probably don't need `.length`, and even if it's a string, I doubt that will work they way you're expecting) you probably want to build a string inside the function, and then return that. Returning from inside your loop will only ever return a single number (A function only returns once)

Comment: Thanks! That was an oversight from my madness! I started throwing random things in there to make sure I wasn't bugging. num is an int...

Answer (score 2):

```js
function theJob(limit) {
  var res = ''; //initialize as a string so that the other numbers will be appended instead of added
  for (i = 0; i <= limit; i += 2) { // step increase by 2 to skip odd numbers
      res += i;
  }
  return res; // returning the resulting string
}

console.log(theJob(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the first number you find. a better approach would be to build the string in the loop then return after that string after the loop. Also no need for num.length if num is an int.

```
function stringOfEvens(num) {
    var stringToReturn = "";
    for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            stringToReturn = stringToReturn + i;
        }
    }
    return stringToReturn;
}
```

Comment: It definitely helped me, so I'm upvoting! Even though my rep is too low for that to matter... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using the modular function, by simply starting the loop at zero and incrementing by 2 each time the loop iterates...

```js
function stringOfEvens(num) {
  var result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i <= num; i += 2) {
    result += i; // append this even number to the result string
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(stringOfEvens(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, since it's not particularly efficient:

```
const stringOfEvens = n => Array(~~(n/2)+1).fill().map((_, i) => 2*i).join("")
```

or annotated:

```
const stringOfEvens = n =>           // arrow function definition, returning:
     Array(~~(n / 2) +1)         // a sparse array of the required length
    .fill()                          // made unsparse, so .map works
    .map((_, i) => 2 * i)            // then containing the even numbers
    .join("")                        // and converted to a string
```

or alternatively (and more efficiently) using `Array.from` which can call an explicit map function in place:

```
const stringOfEvens = n => Array.from(Array(~~(n/2)+1), (_, i) => 2*i).join("")
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function stringOfEvens(num) {
var str= ' ';
for(var i = 0; i <= num; i = i + 2){
str += i;
}
return str;
}
console.log(stringOfEvens(10))
```